# Bootstrap tabs with next/previous buttons quit working after a few clicks

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have some html that uses bootstrap tabs and next/prev buttons to navigate between parts of a form. When I click through the next buttons the first time, it works fine, but when I click next, previous, and then next again it quits working. Not sure what the issue is since it works fine the first go around.

Working copy on js bin: https://jsbin.com/qeyiwawugo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="applicationTab">
                    <p>Form for selecting application</p>
                    <a href="#cmgTab" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Next</a>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="cmgTab">
                    <p>Form for selecting CMG</p>
                    <a href="#applicationTab" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Prev</a>
                    <a href="#patientListTab" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Next</a>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="patientListTab">
                    <p>Form for selecting patient list</p>
                    <a href="#cmgTab" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Prev</a>
                    <a href="#alertsTab" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Next</a>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="alertsTab">
                    <p>Form for setting alerts</p>
                    <a href="#patientListTab" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Prev</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console output ? Can't really help you without a working example.

Comment: @MihaiT No errors

Comment: Update: the next button is actually getting disabled somehow

Comment: Edit your question and add your html to a 'snippet'; it's on the menu. In the snippet you can add bootstrap, and/or links to js libraries. Try to recreate exactly what you have so we can see the problem as you do.

Comment: @wazz added a link to jsbin